# Embedded Signing request DocuSign API fails on certain envelopes

Tags: ruby, docusignapi

We submit a CreateRecipient request to get a document signing URL:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient/

To identify the user we provide `user_id` and `client_user_id` as per documentation(`client_user_id` has a valid string value). And most of the time but in a fraction of cases it fails with the following:

```json
{
"errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT", 
"message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."
}
```

We request values for `user_id` and `client_user_id` from the [Envelopes -> Get Envelope](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/get/) `envelope -> recipients -> signers`, so there is no chance id's are incorrect.

```
DocuSign_eSign::Signer

 @client_user_id="gid://platform/Client/617983",
 @delivery_method="email",
 @embedded_recipient_start_url="SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN",
 @recipient_id="1",
 @recipient_id_guid="98e4bd97-a0b0-4c66-8b5d-7cca21813b04",
 @recipient_type="signer",
 @require_id_lookup="false",
 @require_upload_signature="false",
 @role_name="Client",
 @routing_order="1",
 @user_id="ad1bed21-ef62-4f37-af4c-909b0e95e7e3">
```

and the request is:

```
{
  "authenticationMethod": "none",
  "clientUserId": "gid://platform/Client/617983",
  "returnUrl": "...",
  "userID": "ad1bed21-ef62-4f37-af4c-909b0e95e7e3"
}
```

Using `email` and `userName` for the same failing envelope doesn't help.

We assume there is a bug in API, but it's hard to tell which signer actions activate such malfunctioning.

Recently affected envelope ids:

```
[
"357ed66b-866a-42c5-9304-23931a6daaee", 
"9a900c0b-ca76-45ac-818b-3e38e1a0638a", 
"5eb84ec3-a7ef-47a0-94bd-2842fe768f93", 
"98934b17-674a-4be2-a6f3-2767821de395", 
"05a09768-c3d6-4fe8-9654-85ce3e07b276"
]
```

We have checked this question: [UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT but the recipients actually do match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500630/unknown-envelope-recipient-but-the-recipients-actually-do-match) but since we identify signer by `userID` and `clientUserID` it doesn't seem relevant. Anyways we checked the recipient via by listing recipient and it matches perfectly.

PS Signing via email link works though.

Comment: Sorry you're having this problem. It is a puzzle since you say that it works most, but not all of the time. I suggest that you contact DocuSign developer support for them to trace the envelopes that fail.

Answer (score 0):

I looked in the logs and saw the same thing you're seeing.
The request is for the wrong user/recipient.

Typically, when specifying these:

```
view_request.email = signer_email
view_request.user_name = signer_name
```

They have to match exactly (including case) to what's in the envelope.

If you use a userId, that has to match to how the envelope was sent. I would confirm that using email and user_name should work if you put the correct values. You can find these values by doing a GET on the envelope with all information included.

Comment: Hi Inbar, would be of great use if you've provided right and wrong values that you've found in the logs. What I actually do is GET envelope and pick signer `clientUserId ` and `userID`. I am struggling to get how come I get it and send it back and it's incorrect.

Comment: The logs don't show these values for privacy reasons and compliance

Comment: Ok, but it only means that we're back where we started. We are talking about abstract ID's - are they subject to privacy?

Comment: Try to do this with email and name, can you do that?

Comment: Yeah it was among the first things we tried. We just fetch envelope signer data from API and set `clientUserId` and `userId`  - it didn't work, then we tried `email`  and `name` and it failed as well. We tried different combinations. I have a feeling that something else is wrong as it happens on very low volume of contracts.

Comment: Nothing is different in those that fail? they are EXACTLY the same as the rest? we need to isolate the culprit